# UDP multicast with multiple interfaces not working

Tags: c, linux, udp, multicast

I have 2 network interfaces

```
 enp5s0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d8:cb:8a:c3:4d:61  
          inet addr:192.168.1.3  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::dacb:8aff:fec3:4d61/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2607:fa48:6d42:4230::1003/128 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

ens6      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a0:36:9f:57:0b:ac  
          inet addr:192.168.1.5  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a236:9fff:fe57:bac/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

listening for UDP multicast packets from `224.1.1.1:5007` but packets are only received by my program when running on `enp5s0` which happens to be the default interfaces.

I'm using the following code to select the interface based on it's IP based on what I read [here](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Multicast-HOWTO-6.html). But it doesn't seem to work.

```
struct ip_mreq mc_addr = {};                                                
mc_addr.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr("224.1.1.1");                      
mc_addr.imr_interface.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]);                          
int rv = setsockopt(s, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_IF,  &mc_addr.imr_interface, sizeof(mc_addr.imr_interface)); 
if(rv < 0) {
    perror("IP_MULTICAST_IF");                                              
}                                                                           
rv = setsockopt(s, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP,  &mc_addr, sizeof(mc_addr)); 
if(rv < 0) {                                                                
    perror("IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP");                                            
}
```

If I use `enp5s0` everything works fine but when using `ens6` I receive nothing even though I can see activity on my switch and in wireshark. Even more confusing is that if I start my program twice with each one running one interface each both programs receive packets.

So why isn't my program receiving packets when using only `ens6`?

Comment: What parameters to you pass to `bind`?

Comment: @dbush I've been reading some other posts and realized I needed to bind with `INADDR_ANY` which I wasn't doing. I changed this but the problem remains. I can only seem to receive when both interfaces are running.

Answer (score 0):

In a multihomed host you generally need to join via all available interfaces, unless you know that multicasts will only be arriving via one of them. Otherwise the IGMP join message doesn't go to all possible routers.

Comment: The hosts are connected through a single switch with IGMP Snooping + Querying enabled. I can see in the IGMP table that both interfaces/ports have joined in the groups. So I don't think IGMP is the problem.